# Объединение элементов двух массивов поочередно

Tags: php

Существует два массива:

```
$ar = array('1','2','3');
$ar2 = array('1a','1b','1c');
```

Нужно объединить их таким образом, что бы получилось `[1,1a,2,1b,3,1c]`, но результат `1a2b3123`

Делаю следующим образом, но не получается:

Comment: Ну почитайте, что делает `array_merge` для начала.
Ну и подсказка  - если это учебное задание, то я бы соединял массивы в цикле. А алгоритм додумайте.
Алсо вариант, должен подойти `array_merge_recursive`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array('a','b','c');
$array3 = array();

$cnt = min(count($array1), count($array2));

for ($i = 0; $ i < $cnt; $i++) {
  $array3[] = $array1[$i];
  $array3[] = $array2[$i];
}

for ($i = $cnt; $ i < count(array1); $i++) {
  $array3[] = $array1[$i];
}


for ($i = $cnt; $ i < count(array2); $i++) {
  $array3[] = $array2[$i];
}
```

Comment: ну че сразу ответ то =)))
Так не интересно.

Comment: то что нужно=) еще добавить надо для вывода **foreach($array3 as $arr){   echo $arr; }**

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно рассмотреть и такое:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array('a','b','c');
$array3 = array();

array_map(function($a, $b) use(&$array3) { array_push($array3, $a, $b);}, $array1, $array2);

print_r($array3);
```

https://3v4l.org/LLWUV

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array('a','b','c');
$array3 = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= (count($array1) - 1); $i++)
{
        $array3[] = $array1[$i];
        $array3[] = $array2[$i];
}


var_export($array3);
```